# iOS Swift pagecontroller offset relative all the controllers content

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

Evening, I'm trying to retrieve the relative position of a page in a page controller...

In a scrollview you would do like so: `scrollview.offset.x / scrollview.frame.width`

What I've done:

first of all I've attached the delegate to the page controller scroll view:

```
let scrollView = pageController.view.subviews.filter { $0 is UIScrollView }.first as! UIScrollView
        scrollView.delegate = self
```

than in the didScroll method I'm trying to calculate the relative offset. But the `scrollview.contentOfsset.x`it's not the total for all the controllers..

Any help with the maths?

Comment: `UIPageViewController` doesn't work like that. If you have 100 "pages" you don't get them laid-out side-by-side. Why are you trying to get the "offset"? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I need it for a progression fade animation

Comment: Then `UIPageViewController` is probably not the correct class to use.

Comment: Now I'm using a scrollview, and I'm adding to it all the views of all the subControllers